# quizaccress_proctoring plugin version.php

Tags: plugins, version, moodle

I installed quizaccess_ proctoring plugin in moodle 3.6. I have updated the plugin version. but when i installed it give the erros version .php file no found

I updated requiured version in plugin. on updating it gives error version.php file not found

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that don't exists a file named version.php inside the plugin directory. Every plugin of Moodle require this file.

Make sure that when you unzip the plugin, the structure of the directory maintains the same.

It must be `/mod/quiz/accessrule/proctoring/version.php`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you downloaded the latest version of the plugin? The latest version does have a version file

https://github.com/eLearning-BS23/moodle-quizaccess_proctoring/blob/master/version.php

Also double check the plugin is in the correct directory

```
/mod/quiz/accessrule/proctoring
```

[https://github.com/eLearning-BS23/moodle-quizaccess_proctoring#:~:text=/mod/quiz/accessrule/proctoring](https://github.com/eLearning-BS23/moodle-quizaccess_proctoring#:%7E:text=/mod/quiz/accessrule/proctoring)